# Horizontal GridView with uneven or merged cells

Tags: android, gridview, horizontal-scrolling

I need to display data in horizontal scrolling gridview. Currently I use TwoWayGridView: https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview, but I need to change grid items to uneven (more specifically - merged) cells. My gridview should look like this:

### [image: Horizontal GridView]

Do you have any advices of how to build that kind of view?

Unfortunately It can't be simple horizontal ScrollView, because I need to show a lot of images, so I guess It can't be done without any view recycler.

Shoud I build my own implementation of AdapterView or extend any existing?

Perfect solution for me, would be Android implementation of UICollectionView from iOS, but I guess that it not exists.

Answer (score 1):

i too have faced similar situation , i solved it by using Grid Layout (not gridview) in a horizontal-scroll-view , i agree that its not the optimized solution , but worth implementing,
one thing in my case was i just have to show the text no images were there.

here is the view i created :- 
[image]

you have to span your rows and column carefully for this you can refer following questions
[How to make a GridLayout fit screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347846/how-to-use-the-gridlayout-to-fit-screen-size)

[Set rowSpan or colSpan of a child of a GridLayout programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532084/set-rowspan-or-colspan-of-a-child-of-a-gridlayout-programmatically)

and use view tag to identify the view if you are implementing any click or touch listener , as i have not found any other way to locate the view other than using its tag !!

hope it helps !!

Answer (score 0):

There is a component called StaggeredGridView that allows you to make uneven tiles while keeping recycling opitimizations. There is a port of it somewhere on github, though I had some trouble with it and just took implementation directly from android sources (the component isn't public yet).

The last time I used it it wasn't quite ready, so some functionality I had to add myself, but nothing too criminal there, just some minor things